# How to set fixed height to apex:repeat tag in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, repeat, scrolling

I am trying to set fixed height to apex:repeat tag, so that page can show scroll bar, but I am unable to set fixed height to apex:repeat. Please let me know how to set height to apex:repeat tag. below is my sample code.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
</tr>
<div style="height:200px;">
    <apex:repeat value="{!quoteLineItemList}" var="quoteLine" >
        <tr>
            <td><apex:outputfield value="{!quoteLine.Product2.Name}"/></td>
            <td><apex:outputfield value="{!quoteLine.Quantity}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a div inside a table like that. Instead, you'll want to look at something like this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17380697/2132791).

```
<style>
<!-- copied from the Stack Overflow answer linked above -->
thead, tbody { display: block; }

tbody {
    height: 100px;       /* Just for the demo          */
    overflow-y: auto;    /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}
</style>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <apex:repeat value="{!quoteLineItemList}" var="quoteLine" >
        <tr>
            <td><apex:outputfield value="{!quoteLine.Product2.Name}"/></td>
            <td><apex:outputfield value="{!quoteLine.Quantity}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</tbody>
</table>
```